# Typing niqqud in a text document

Tags: input-language, hebrew

I run Ubuntu in English, but I would sometimes like to type in Hebrew with niqqud. I've got Hebrew as a possible layout for an input source and can switch to that keyboard layout, but I can't find the AltGr combination that makes this possible. How do I type these symbols?

To give an example, Biblical Hebrew very often has symbols around the letters to indicate vowels. Here is an example sentence:

וַיְחִ֤י יַעֲקֹב֙ בְּאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם שְׁבַ֥ע עֶשְׂרֵ֖ה שָׁנָ֑ה וַיְהִ֤י יְמֵֽי־יַעֲקֹב֙ שְׁנֵ֣י חַיָּ֔יו שֶׁ֣בַע שָׁנִ֔ים וְאַרְבָּעִ֥ים וּמְאַ֖ת שָׁנָֽה׃

Those tiny dots below, above and sometimes inside the letters are called niqqud. Looking at the first letter:
וַ
The
ו
is easy to type with a Hebrew keyboard layout. What I'm asking for help with is the line underneath it.

Comment: Yes, I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing what I'm doing, with the Hebrew layout I can for instance press:

<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

which gives me הְ (have no idea if that makes sense).

The point I'm trying to make is that you need to first type the letter and add punctuation etc. afterwards.

A couple of tips:

- When the Hebrew layout is selected, you can choose "Show keyboard layout" from the input source indicator to see a graphical overview.
- The actual layout can be found in the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/il`.